# Android EditText password, label gravitiy RTL

Tags: android, android-edittext, right-to-left

I spent a lot of time in attempt to resolve this issue but without success for now...

when the application runs on android with RTL language. the label(hint) of the EditText is shown at the wrong position.

Desired result
[ltr layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiYRT.png)

RTL Layout
[rtl layou](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DQEH.png)

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Login form container -->
    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/form_container"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_widthPercent="85%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="30%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="8%">

        <!-- Username layout -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
                android:textDirection="ltr"
                android:hint="@string/hint_username"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Password layout -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/input_layout_username">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textDirection="anyRtl"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

how can i fix the unnecessary margin in the RTL layout?
In addition, it would be great if it's possible to remove/hide the "visibility toggle"(eye icon) button!

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your xml code

Comment: i forgot to attach the xml code, sorry for that... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to disable password toggle all you need is to add "passwordToggleEnabled" attribute to your TextInputLayout, for example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="false">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textDirection="ltr"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```